# How to get a history of SQL queries made in CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

I'd like to search, perhas using `grep`, through the history of all SQL queries in a CockroachDB cluster. Is that possible?

I hope that there is a file that stores each and every single SQL queries I ever issued to my CockroachDB cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can find the file `~/.cockroachsql_history` to store all of the SQL queries you ever issued through the SQL shell. However, that file encoded all "special characters" (non-alphanumerical, non-underscore characters) with their Octal ASCII code.

You can, however, find and replace those encodings to their origins using the following command

```
perl -plw -e 's/\\134/\\/g; s/\\040/ /g; s/\\011/\t/g; s/\\012/\n/g' ~/.cockroachsql_history > ~/.cockroachsql_history_replaced
```

where I simply try to replace all the special character encodings I found in my `~/.cockroachsql_history`. If it misses any for yours, simply add one more clause in the one-line perl program (the pattern is `s/old_string/new_string/g;`).